Dynamically get data from running flowgraph in gnuradio
I would like to be able to get data "between" blocks from a running flowgraph in gnuradio (3.10). I would like to do this from python without stopping/locking the flowgraph, if possible. Here is a step-by-step example of what I am hoping to accomplish:

Start the flowgraph (containing block some block A) from python.
Let the flowgraph run a bit
Make some call or dynamically attach some new block without interrupting execution that allows me to access the data exiting block A.

Originally I tried doing this by dynamically attaching a sink block that sent the data out over a socket. However, it seems that you have to lock/unlock the flowgraph in order to do this which, from what I can tell, interrupts the execution.
